# Nginx: allow only certain cookies in http response

Tags: nginx, cookies, playframework

I'm using playframework and nginx. playframework may add following cookies to http response: PLAY_SESSION, PLAY_FLASH, PLAY_LANG. 
I want to make sure that only above cookies (PLAY_*) are allowed in nginx level. If there are other cookies (let's say they're added accidentally) they should be removed by nginx. 
How can I allow only predefined cookies in http response in nginx?

PS: If it's not possible to solve this issue in nginx, I need to fix by using playframework.

Comment: Here the example of handling cookies in nginx lua module: http://ywebdev.com/?p=77 You can exsely modify it for your needs.

Comment: @AndriyKuba Thanks for advice. I tried to install lua module from [here](http://openresty.org/en/linux-packages.html) for Kubuntu 16.04. I had a nginx installed and I had to stop it. Then I installed openresty successfully. Then I couldn't run nginx and I realized that openresty is a replacement for nginx. So I can't replace nginx with openresty. I might use a module for nginx.

Comment: Any chance you can provide samples (complete headers) of the cookies that should be passed?  E.g., path etc?

Comment: Also, can you clarify the rationale?  Are there certain other cookies that you specifically want to remove?  What's the purpose of these `PLAY_` cookies?  Why do you want these cookies allowed, and other blocked?  E.g., I found that it was best to simply block all cookies in my installations: https://serverfault.com/a/467774/110020, and I instead use `$uri` to specify stuff that would otherwise go into the cookies.

Comment: @cnst Usually I've got only one session cookie. It's controlled by [playframework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSessionFlash). It looks like this in http response:

`Set-Cookie:PLAY_SESSION=eyJhbG...iIE; SameSite=Lax; Path=/; HTTPOnly` 

I've got only whitelisted cookies which should be allowed. I want other cookies are blocked because it's client's request.

Comment: So, you want to block cookies from the client?  Or from the server?  Blocking cookies from the client makes sense, since you may want to make sure they wouldn't be able to exploit stuff or spoil your cache.  But blocking cookies from the upstream server's http response makes less sense, since if someone's already controlling the server, they could also set cookies from JavaScript anyways.

Comment: @cnst Blocking cookies from the server's http response.

Comment: @Ikrom I still think that's a pretty unusual request; can you possibly clarify the rationale for whitelisting?  If the client controls your backend already, they can already issue cookies through JavaScript, and nginx config wouldn't be the best place to solve that.

Answer (score 10):

## How cookies work?

First, let's establish what's cookies — they're little pieces of "sticky" hidden information that lets you keep state on your web-site for a given User-Agent.  These cookies are often used for tracking users, keeping session and storing minor preference information for the site.

- ### `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header (from server to client)

  Cookies can be set by the server through the ***`Set-Cookie`*** response header ([with a separate header for each cookie](//stackoverflow.com/questions/11533867/set-cookie-header-with-multiple-cookies)), or, after the page has already been transferred from the server to the client, through JavaScript.

  Note that setting cookies is a pretty complex job — they have expiration dates, http/https settings, path etc — hence the apparent necessity to use a separate `Set-Cookie` header for each cookie.

  This requirement to have a separate header is usually not an issue, since cookies aren't supposed to be modified all that often, as they usually store very minimal information, like a session identifier, with the heavy-duty information being stored in an associated database on the server.
- ### `Cookie` HTTP request header (from client to server)

  Regardless how they were first set, cookies would then included in eligible subsequent requests to the server by the client, using the ***`Cookie`*** request header, with a whole list of eligible cookies in one header.

  Note that, as such, these cookies that are sent by the client back to the server is a simple list of name and attribute pairs, without any extra information about the underlying cookies that store these attributes on the client side (e.g., the expiration dates, http/https setting and paths are saved by the client internally, but without being revealed in subsequent requests to the server).

  This conciseness of the `Cookie` request header field is important, because, once set, eligible cookies will be subsequently included in all forthcoming requests for all resources with the eligible scheme / domain / path combination.

---

## Caching issues with cookies.

The normal [issue of using cookies, especially in the context of acceleration and nginx](//serverfault.com/a/467774/110020), is that:

- cookies invalidate the cache by default (e.g., unless you use [`proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ignore_headers)),
- or, if you do sloppy configuration, cookies could possibly spoil your cache

  - e.g., through the client being able to pass cookies to the upstream in the absence of [`proxy_set_header Cookie "";`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header),
  - or, through the server insisting on setting a cookie through the absence of [`proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_hide_header).

---

## How nginx handles cookies?

- ### `Cookie` from the client

  Note that nginx does support looking through the cookies that the client sends to it (in the ***`Cookie`*** request header) through the [`$cookie_name`](http://nginx.org/r/$cookie_) scheme.

  If you want to limit the client to only be sending certain cookies, you could easily re-construct the `Cookie` header based on these variables, and send only whichever ones you want to the upstream (using `proxy_set_header` as above).

  Or, you could even make decisions based on the cookie to decide which upstream to send the request to, or to have a per-user/per-session [`proxy_cache_key`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_key), or make access control decisions based on the cookies.
- ### `Set-Cookie` from the backend

  As for the upstream sending back the cookies, you can, of course, [decide to block it all to considerably improve the caching characteristics](//serverfault.com/a/467774/110020) (if applicable to your application, or parts thereof), or fix up the domain and/or path with [`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cookie_domain) and/or [`proxy_cookie_path`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cookie_path), respectively.

  Otherwise, it's generally too late to make any other routing decision — the request has already been processed by the selected upstream server, and the response is ready to be served — so, naturally, there doesn't seem to be a way to look into these individual ***`Set-Cookie`*** cookies through normal means in nginx (unless you want to go third-party modules, or lua, or perl), since it'd already be too late to make any important routing decisions for a completed request.

  Basically, these `Set-Cookie` cookies have more to do with the content than with the way it is served or routed, so, it doesn't seem appropriate to have integrated functionality to look into them through nginx.

  (If you do need to make routing decisions after the completion of the request, then nginx does support `X-Accel-Redirect`, as well as some other special headers.)

  If your issue is security, then, as I've pointed out above, the upstream developer can already use JavaScript to set ANY extra cookies however they want, so, effectively, trying to use nginx to limit some, but not all, `Set-Cookie` responses from the server is kind of a pointless endeavour in the real world (as there is hardly any difference between the cookies set through JavaScript compared to `Set-Cookie`).

---

## In summary:

- you can easily examine and reconstruct the `Cookie` header sent by the client to the server before passing it over to the backend, and only include the sanctioned cookies in the request to upstream backend,
- but, unless you want to use lua/perl, or have your own nginx module (as well as possibly quarantine the JavaScript from the pages you serve), then you cannot pass only certain `Set-Cookie` headers back from the upstream backend to the client with a stock nginx.conf — with the `Set-Cookie` headers, it's an all-or-nothing situation, and there doesn't seem to be a good-enough use-case for a distinct approach.

Answer (score 3):

For an Nginx solution it might be worth asking over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). Here is a potential solution via Play Framework.

```scala
package filters

import javax.inject._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class ExampleFilter @Inject()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends EssentialFilter {
  override def apply(next: EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request =>
    next(request).map { result =>
      val cookieWhitelist = List("PLAY_SESSION", "PLAY_FLASH", "PLAY_LANG")
      val allCookies = result.newCookies.map(c => DiscardingCookie(c.name))
      val onlyWhitelistedCookies = result.newCookies.filter(c => cookieWhitelist.contains(c.name))

      result.discardingCookies(allCookies: _*).withCookies(onlyWhitelistedCookies: _*)
    }
  }
}
```

This solution utilizes [Filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaHttpFilters) and [`Result` manipulation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaResults#Setting-and-discarding-cookies). Do test for adverse effects on performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Next time I'll ask nginx related question on serverfault. Your code works fine and I'll use it as a last resort. But I'm still hoping nginx solution.